# How to bundle multiple files in nested directory in gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, bundle

I am using gulp and what I need to do is to bundle all the files in multiple nested directories in `node_modlues` folder to `public/js/libName` and `dist/js/libName` so that I can use that module in my client.

```
dist 
   js 
node_modules 
   test_library
       file1.js
       file2.js 
       folder1
           file1.js
           file2.js
       folder2
           file3.js
           file4.js         
public
    js
```

Comment: If  you are using gulp, then surely  you can share your current config or what you have tried?

Comment: What do you mean by "bundle" them? Concatenate them together? Use something like webpack?

Comment: @Icepickle I tried to make it work by `gulp-concat` and `browserify` but I had to add all those files one by one, I need to bundle everything in `test-library` at the same time not adding them one by one.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara yes, kinda like `import x from y`.

Comment: I am pretty much guessing here, but wouldn't it be something like `gulp.src(['node_modules/**/public/js/index.js', node_modules/**/dist/js/index.js']) .pipe(minify()).pipe(gulp.dest('build'));`

Comment: @Icepickle very close, but I need to read from `node_modules` and put it in `public` and `dist`

Comment: Did you [RTM](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#optionsbase)? I mean, I just assumed after reading that one for 5 minutes, I don't even have gulp installed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently solved similar task this way:

**require:**

src/bundle_entrypoint.js (bundle entrypoint):

```
require('jquery');

// your code
```

gulpfile:

```
// init base modules

// additional modules
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');

// reg build tasks, etc

gulp.task('build-bundle', function() {    
  return browserify({
      entries: 'src/bundle_entrypoint.js',
      debug: true,
      paths: ['./node_modules'],
      cache: {},
      packageCache: {}
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(uglifyOrWhateverYouWant())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js/'));
});
```

**EDIT:**

**concat:**

```
gulp.task('build-bundle', function() {    
      return gulp.src(['node_modules/test_library/**/*.js','src/my.js'])
        .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(uglifyOrWhateverYouWant())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js/'));
    });
```

Comment: to read all the js files in node_modules/myModule should I use `entries: '**/**.js',` ?

Comment: but it doesnt make sense. npm modules should be already built in dist folder. why do you want to concat all js through subdirs? concat will merge these files in walkdir order and if this subtree represents complex library, it can break its functionality..

Comment: try npm install elasticsearch and bower install elasticsearch. both are the same version but for a specific query, the bower version cannot aggregate results but npm version does. so basically i need to use node version of elastic search intro the client. thats it.

Comment: Sorry. I clicked on some outdated module. I found module that you mentioned and there are two versions. elasticsearch and elasticsearch-browser. Make sure that you have right one.